# read characters at specific position in screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible to read characters on screen (precise: in a screen session, coming from legacy software w/ ncurses interface)?

Unluckily, the (quite simple) API of the software we are running in a screen-session does not allow access to some important status messages, that are only displayed "on screen".

So, the question is: can we access the "char buffer" of a screen session **from outside**? I.E. sth. like => `getChars(x=5, y=30, length=5; screen-pid=12345)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the screen buffer is the property of the terminal emulator (not part of the 'tty' itself). Some terminal emulators allow accessing their screen buffer externally, others don't.

GNU Screen supports this using the `:hardcopy` command (although in my quick test, it *completely* mangled all non-ASCII text that was supposed to be UTF-8). Use `screen -X` to invoke it externally:

```
screen -X hardcopy /tmp/foo
```

The equivalent functionality in tmux (using `capture-pane` and `save-buffer`) seems to work much better:

```
tmux capture-pane -t <id> \; save-buffer /tmp/foo \; delete-buffer
```

---

(For completeness: The Linux virtual console also allows this, using [peekvc](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/peekvc/).)

---

Sometimes you might find it more useful to write a custom "host" program using a terminal emulation library (such as [libvterm](https://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libvterm/)) – create a pty, run the software attached to it, then use libvterm to process the ncurses "drawing" sequences directly into your own buffer.

Comment: +1. I would use `tmux capture-pane -p …` and redirect or pipe the output. `save-buffer` is not needed then.

Comment: Super: screen hardcopy will do and is all we need! Thanks @user1686